# get value by element xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
<input id="ctl00_MainContent_AllowanceGridView_ctl46_DHD" 
class="allowanceValue" type="text" 
onkeydown="return formattime(this,event);" value="00:56" name="ctl00$MainContent$AllowanceGridView$ctl46$DHD"/>
```

How to get value=00:56, by seleniun, Java ?
Tried using `.getText();`, but it doesn't get me the value ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: What does `getText()` give you? Basically, we can't answer this question as it currently sits.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch there was an HTML code inside the answer - it was not just displayed properly. Consider removing the downvote. Thanks.

Comment: @alecxe I wasn't the downvoter.

Comment: @alecxe Also not a close voter. Although the question has 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the element [by id](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/By.html#id(java.lang.String)) and then get the `value` attribute using [`getAttribute()`](https://selenium.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute(java.lang.String)):

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("ctl00_MainContent_AllowanceGridView_ctl46_DHD"));
System.out.println(element.getAttribute("value"));
```